# I am facing issue with Power Automate group by column to send email

Tags: power-automate

**This is my Data:**

[image]

**And This is how I wanted to group it and send it in an email**

[image]

Comment: How do I send this data group by name, so that in one email for all common name  records

Comment: So you want to filter on each distinct "Name" and send an email for everyone containing all records for the distinct name?

Comment: Also, can you provide the associated JSON?  We typically don't work with the Excel data directly unless you want to use Office Scripts.

Comment: I'm confused, you are not doing any grouping here? It looks like you want to select a particular name.

Comment: {
    "body": [
        {
            "Sheet1[Name]": "ABC1",
            "Sheet1[Date]": "2023-06-17T00:00:00",
            "[AverageScore]": 6
        },
        {
            "Sheet1[Name]": "ABC1",
            "Sheet1[Date]": "2023-06-12T00:00:00",
            "[AverageScore]": 1
        },
        {
            "Sheet1[Name]": "ABC1",
            "Sheet1[Date]": "2023-06-21T00:00:00",
            "[AverageScore]": 10
        },
        {
            "Sheet1[Name]": "ABC2",
            "Sheet1[Date]": "2023-06-13T00:00:00",
            "[AverageScore]": 2
        }}